# How to stop Chrome from trying to load a page again automatically?

Tags: google-chrome

When developing and debugging web-apps it becomes very annoying when Chrome automatically retries to load a page again by itself. This happens when the page initially returns for instance 404 or other error and I go back to my code-editor to fix the issue, but don't immediately want Chrome to try again by itself. I want to trigger the reload explicitly by myself when I'm ready to debug the site again. Is there a setting for this? Note, this is not the same as automatic tab-refresing. I only have one tab open but it keeps reloading randomly until it gets a 200-response. I only want to trigger the reload manually.

Comment: Pulling my hair out over this!